# How can I make my bot check if the author has administrator and send a message if they don't?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have made a command that I want to be accessible to only admins. If the user has admin, a specific code runs. If not, I want the bot to send a message like "Sorry, you cannot use that". Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def command(self, ctx):
          #code here
```

Would make the command `command` admin only.
As for warning the user for trying to run a command they don't have permission for, you can use an error handler / command specific error handler.
Such as

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingPermissions):
            msg.title = "Missing Permission ⛔"
            msg.description = error.args[0]
            return await ctx.send(embed=msg)
```

For a cog specific error, use commandname.error() and catch the error like shown above.